# Is there any size limitation of ipad application?

Tags: ipad, size, limit

I know maximum size of application in app store is 2GB. and we can only download 20MB apps through 3G and unlimited through wifi.

What about a application that wouldn't be put into app store, is there any limit?

Also, is there any guru know any performance issue when the application is big? what is the ideal limit if there is any, i am not talking the physical limit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, if the app isn't going to be reviewed by Apple, you can do anything you want and it can be any size. Also, the size of the application does not relate to its performance, the amount of resources it uses does.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, i will try sqlite3 for external storage.